# How to hook up wireless charging pad to battery of my motor (Honda CBR500R 2020)

Tags: electrical, battery, motorcycle, accessories

I want to hook up the following wireless charging pad in combination with my RAM mount X grip to my motorcycle's battery. I am a complete noob when it comes to this electronics. How can I make sure I connect it properly? I think I need a resistor and voltage step down board?

The purpose of it is to charge my phone.

My motor battery output is 12V 7Ah (Honda CBR500R 2020 stock battery)

https://www.spigen.com/collections/wireless-charger/products/steadiboost-compact-10w-wireless-charger?variant=31576598839343

Is it true that when I leave it connected overnight, the battery will drain (

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a usb 12v to 5v adapter/charger if your wireless charger comes with a 110vac wall charger. Presuming the wireless charger has a usb plug to connect to a cube for home charging, a12 usb adapter/charger will work for cars, trucks, suvs and motorcycles. You may have to check your wireless power specs and whether or not it will draw more than a few amps as most vehicle usb adapters limit current to around 2 amps.  Typical dc adapters for a few dollars from most auto stores. They plug into the power outlet/cigarette lighter socket. If your motorcycle doesn't have one then this complicates things as you'll have to either wire up the adapter into a switched, fused circuit that shuts off when the ignition key is turned off or have someone familiar with motorcycle electrical wiring perform the modification. If wired into a live wire then the combination usb adapter/wireless charger will always draw current that can drain a battery. Be sure the ram mount can hold the wireless pad and your phone rigidly. You don't want a flimsy phone mount to loosen its grip on every bump and pothole that wasn't avoided unless you're only charging when parked.

Comment: Thank you! So I need a USB 12V to 5V adapter (that is connected via live wire to my battery) and inbetween the wireless charger and the adapter a switch that either turns off when ignition is off or when I turn it off

Comment: Yes, a 12v to 5v usb adapter to match your wireless charger. Wire the adapter between a switched circuit in the ignition system. This switches off the adapter when ignition is turned off to prevent draining the battery.  The key is switching off the adapter. Charge while driving.